# Regex pattern to extract PHPSESSID value from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, sessionid

I am having some issues with `preg_match()`. 
I used this code (and it used to worked pretty well in the past):

```
preg_match("/PHPSESSID=(.*?)(?:;|\r\n)/", $code, $phpsessid);
```

but now it's not working anymore. (returns an empty array).

My subject : `HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Server: nginx/1.8.0 Date: Wed, 24 May 2017 08:58:57 GMT Content-Type: text/html Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18 Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=jrq8446q91fv6eme2ois3lpl07; expires=Thu, 24-May-2018 08:58:57 GMT; path=/; Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate Location: index.php
*`

I need to get the PHPSESSID value: `jrq8446q91fv6eme2ois3lpl07`

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: [It works](https://regex101.com/r/JqQb3B/1).

Comment: What does "not anymore" mean? What did you change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not grouping the ? with the (.*) so:

```
preg_match("/PHPSESSID=(.*)?(:;|\r\n)?/", $code, $phpsessid);
```

Comment: Good, still Lasse's solution is better. Only use this for parsing full headers if no other options are available.

Answer (score 2):

Given the OP's input string...

The OP's pattern works [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZnYkoO/2)  (131 steps)

The currently accepted answer is **incorrect** -- this will surely confuse future readers.  [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZnYkoO/1)

But let's make sure you are using the most efficient, most brief, best possible pattern...

```
/PHPSESSID=\K[a-z\d]*/  #no capture group, 23 steps (accurate for sample input)
/PHPSESSID=\K[^;]*/     #no capture group, 23 steps (accurate for sample input)
/PHPSESSID=\K\w*/       #no capture group, 23 steps (not inaccurate, includes underscores)
```

If you expect to see `\r` or `\n` as a possible delimiter for the PHPSESSID value, then you can add those characters to the "negated character class" like this: `[^;\r\n]` (it will still run in 23 steps)  [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZnYkoO/4)

Input:

```
$subject='HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Server: nginx/1.8.0 Date: Wed, 24 May 2017 08:58:57 GMT Content-Type: text/html Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18 Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=jrq8446q91fv6eme2ois3lpl07; expires=Thu, 24-May-2018 08:58:57 GMT; path=/; Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate Location: index.php
*';
```

One-liner Method ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1fd9efeb5e6d73ab542c1d2fe43674a4d9fe9e23)):

```
echo preg_match('/PHPSESSID=\K[^;\r\n]*/',$subject,$out)?$out[0]:'';
```

Output:

```
jrq8446q91fv6eme2ois3lpl07
```

Notice that by using `\K` there is no need to use a capture group, this reduces output array size by 50%.  I hope these best practices educate future readers.

Answer (score 0):

What about http://www.php.net/session_id ?

$sessionid = session_id();

/Lasse

Comment: The subject is taken from another website , so this is not going to work.